# Add instance of class object to list of class objects in class constructor

Tags: class, constructor, kotlin

Sorry for the confusing title. I am trying to add an instance of my class after it passes all the input tests into the PersonList. So far I tried creating an object of my class inside the constructor but that didn't work. Please let me know.

```
open class Person  {
    var _name: String
    var _Id: String
    var disabilities = emptySet<Disability>()

    companion object {
        val PersonList: MutableList<Person> = mutableListOf()
        val PersonId: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    }

    constructor(n: String, i: String){
        _name = n
        _Id = i

        if(_name.isBlank()){
            throw Error("blank string")
        }
        else if(_name.get(0).equals(' ')){
            throw Error("leading zero")
        }
        else if(_Id.toIntOrNull()== null){
            throw Error("Id is not numeric")
        }
        else if(_Id.length != 9) {
            throw Error("Id is not length 9")
        }
        else if(_Id in PersonId){
            throw Error("Person Id is a repeat")
        }
        else {
            PersonList.add()
            PersonId.add(_Id)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding nothing to `PersonList` whose type is `MutableList<Person>`.

I assume you want to add the current `Person` instance to the list.

Then do `PersonList.add(this)`.

That is,

```
    ...
    else {
        PersonList.add(this)
        PersonId.add(_Id)
    }
    ...
```